# How to disable the "newer kernel" warning in debian jessie?

Tags: debian, apt

Debian jessie prompt on every `apt-get upgrade`, that a newer kernel was installed and a reboot is needed. How can this warning be disabled, because i want to reboot when it fits and i know that there is a newer kernel available?

And a similiar dialog is shown for "you need to restart these services because libraries were updated", which is re-shown again and again, even when i already decided "i want to restart this three ones and the two other ones should not be restarted" before.

Comment: It's not offering to perform the reboot, is it? It's just a warning; ignore it.

Comment: If you upgrade a lot of hosts (i.e. via apt-dater) you do not want to acknowledge the warning every time. So your advice is not really helpful.

Answer (score 6):

This is done by the [needrestart package](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/needrestart).

To disable this you can create a file called `/etc/needrestart/conf.d/silence_kernel.conf` with the line `$nrconf{kernelhints} = 0;`

Other available options are listed in [/etc/needrestart/needrestart.conf](https://github.com/liske/needrestart/blob/master/ex/needrestart.conf)